# What is the meaning of "Like the way I feel when I ride my bike fast"?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "Like the way
I feel when I ride my bike fast" in the following sentences?
(Source; My Dad Takes Care Of Me by Patricia Quinlan)

> My dad and I talk about more things now. ***Like the way* I feel when I
>   ride my bike fast.** I told him, "A big kid at school punched me. I
>   was afraid to hit him back." "Sometimes I'm afraid of things too,
>   Luke," he said.

Does "Like the way I feel when I ride my bike fast" mean "I feel like the way when I ride my bike fast" ?

What does "the way" mean in the sentence?

Comment: _The way I feel = how I feel. Like_ refers to _things_. The first two sentences could have been written as one - "We talk about things like (the way I feel when I ride my bike fast)."

Comment: If so, does "My dad and I talk about more things now. Like the way I feel when I ride my bike fast" mean "My dad and I talk about more things now. For example, things are the way I feel when I ride my bike fast"? If  "like" in the sentence mean "For example, things are" ?

Comment: No, "[We talk about] things _such as_ the way I feel…"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example sentences

> **Like the way I feel when I ride my bike fast.**

refers to things in the previous sentence

> My dad and I talk about more things now.
>   *What type of things do you talk about?*
>   Like the way I feel when I ride my bike fast.

Also in your sentences

> **the way**

means

> **how**
>   Like **how** I feel when I ride my bike fast.

Comment: If so, does "Like the way I feel when I ride my bike fast" mean "For example, a type of things is the way I feel when I ride my bike fast" ? Can I think that "like" mean "For example, a type of things is"  ?

Comment: The word **Like** is a similie and can be used for comparisons, eg she looks **like** a boy, so "Like the way I feel when I ride my bike fast" are those feelings you have when riding fast, eg excited, scared, out of control, and free.

Comment: @Peter Yes, it is, _but not in this case_. Here, **like** means **such as**.